# Problems with VPhoneInput (vue vuetify)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js

I'm using VPhoneInput - International phone field for Vuetify 3 and Vue 3. ([link](https://paul-thebaud.github.io/v-phone-input/))

I think I have installed them correctly,

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vue3Lottie from 'vue3-lottie'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' 


import router from '@/router/index.js';

import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'

import 'flag-icons/css/flag-icons.min.css';
import 'v-phone-input/dist/v-phone-input.css';
import { createVPhoneInput } from 'v-phone-input';




import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'


const vPhoneInput = createVPhoneInput({
  countryIconMode: 'svg',
})


const vuetify = createVuetify({
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
    },
  },
  components,
  directives
})


const app = createApp(App)



app.use(Vue3Lottie)
app.use(vuetify)
app.use(router)
app.use(vPhoneInput);
app.use(VueCookies, { expires: '365d'})
app.mount('#app')
```

**signup.vue**

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="signUp">
    <h1 style="font-size: 29px; margin-bottom: 1.5rem; color: rgb(94, 142, 157);">Create Account</h1>
    <v-text-field density="compact" v-model="signUpusername.value.value"
      :error-messages="signUpusername.errorMessage.value" label="Username" autocomplete="username"></v-text-field>

      <v-phone-input country-icon-mode="svg" label="Your Phone number" />


    <v-text-field density="compact" v-model="signUpemail.value.value" :error-messages="signUpemail.errorMessage.value"
      label="E-mail"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field density="compact" type="password" v-model="signUppassword.value.value"
      :error-messages="signUppassword.errorMessage.value" label="Password" autocomplete="new-password"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field density="compact" type="password" v-model="signUpconfirmPassword.value.value"
      :error-messages="signUpconfirmPassword.errorMessage.value" label="Confirm Password"
      autocomplete="new-password"></v-text-field>
    <v-select density="compact" v-model="signUpselect.value.value" :items="items"
      :error-messages="signUpselect.errorMessage.value" label="Country"></v-select>
    <vue-recaptcha ref="recaptcha" @verify="verifyMethod" @expired="expiredMethod"
      sitekey="6Ldlm9goAAAAAIwOi34CmusGSkYb2kLRWRUEIu0e" />


    <div v-if="recaptchaError" class="v-input__details">
      <div class="v-messages" role="alert" aria-live="polite" id="input-22-messages"
        style="color: #B00020; font-weight: 500;">
        <div class="v-messages__message">Please complete the reCAPTCHA challenge</div>
      </div>
      <span></span>
    </div>


    <v-checkbox v-model="signUpcheckbox.value.value" :error-messages="signUpcheckbox.errorMessage.value" value="1"
      label="I Agree With Terms And Conditions" type="checkbox"></v-checkbox>
    <a style="margin-top: 0.5rem !important; margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important; display: block; text-align: left;" href="#"
      @click="$emit('switch-to-signin')">Already a member? Sign in here</a>
    <v-btn type="submit" height="50" class="w-100" style="background: rgb(94, 142, 157); color: white;">Sign Up</v-btn>
  </form>
</template>


> <script> import { ref } from 'vue'; import { useField, useForm } from
> 'vee-validate'; import countries from '@/assets/countries.js'; import
> { VueRecaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha'; import { createUserAccount }
> from '@/firebase.js';
> 
> ... irrelevant code </script>
```

It should look like this

[image]

But it looks like this

[image]

For some reason it creates to separate windows

Also, when I click on country field I get this error-

> Uncaught runtime errors: × ERROR ResizeObserver loop completed with
> undelivered notifications.
> at handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:299:58)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:318:7)

Comment: nothing in your provided code suggests an error or unexpected behavior.  do you have a repo you can share?

Comment: It's a project im working on, not sure if I want to do that